# Installing local binary packages using R CMD INSTALL on a Mac

Tags: r

I came across a package that is not available on CRAN. I tried to install the package using:

> Packages & Data > Package Installer > Local Binary Package > At User
>   Level > [FileName.tgz] > Install...

This didn't work and I am now trying to use the R CMD INSTALL command. However, it seems I need to run that command in the command line interface but I cannot get it to install properly.

The package I'm trying to install is called `gEcon`. It can be found [here](http://gecon.r-forge.r-project.org/download.html). In particular, I am getting the following error message after "installing" the package:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gEcon’:
package ‘gEcon’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

I assume it's the way I'm installing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What package is it?

Comment: It's called gEcon and it isn't intended to be run natively on Mac. However, some third party made it available for Mac binary and the developers published it on their site.

Comment: I'd add a link to it in your question. Incidentally I do the same type of modeling and would recommend (IMHO, FWIW) using other tools builtin (`glm()`, `lm()`, etc) regression tools + `optimr` by John C. Nash for optimization. Not that there's anything wrong with this library, just to let you know you may have options.

Comment: I am updating my answer now that I've seen the website. In the future definitely provide more specific details, they made all the difference in this case. This library is extremely restrictive. I don't like it. I come from an econometrics background so I am curious and will check it out, but I dont like how weirdly restrictive it is.

Comment: I added the link. And yes, this package strictly focuses on solving systems of dynamic equations, so maybe that's why it seems so restrictive.

Comment: How is that different from modeling and optimizing an equation or systems of equation with any of the mainstream libraries? I'm not saying there's not something special about this library, I'm just very unclear on what it is. Perhaps I've been out in the field too long.

Comment: I think what makes this package different from many others is that it uses an algorithm that automatically derives the first order conditions of a given problem and arranges the dynamic equations into a solvable system. So basically, all you do is write a .txt file with a specific structure and the package will solve the model without you having to derive anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to install Xcode apparently, because you've got to install this from source [per these directions](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-packages-from-source-on-mac-os-x/):

Now, you've gotta update R to the latest stable release, or if you prefer you can find the exact minimum newest version needed for gEcon.

After upgrading R you can complete the installation from source.

**Original answer to original question:**

Two things:

1. To access the command line and use `R CMD` on an Apple computer, please use the `terminal.app` app. Please see [this](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-use-terminal-on-mac-3608274/) for more details.
2. An easier and probably better approach is to install your package from the author's Github (or BitBucket, etc) repository using `devtools::install_github` or just use `devtools::install` on the downloaded source project.

Comment: Haha. Yes, I was afraid I would have to install this from source...

Thanks for the advice.